# What bearings go in DT Swiss R23 Spine Disc (FW,RW,Freehub)?

Tags: bearings

I am not longer able to pedal or back-pedal freely. Coasting still works, so I suspect my freehub bearing is the problem. But man... I've been searching for hours now and can't seem to find what bearings need to go in my wheels.

Does anyone of you have a clue?

Comment: No idea about the specific wheelset, but DT swiss has technical manual online. There are a few different freehub body designs, you should be able to find your model there. Then again, if you disassemble the freehub enough to be able to replace the bearings, you should be able to measure them yourself.

Comment: There's no difference in back-pedaling or coasting except relative rotation speed of the freehub and hub. I think you are going to have to get in the hub to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Depending on your handiness, it may work out that a replacement freehub body is more practical. Worth pricing that as an option.   Have you started disassembling the hub?  Could be a flush of lube will get you going again.